# How to lock rows in MySQL with c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, locking

I have select query with two joins and I need to lock selected record (row) for update. 
I've tried to test it in a way to load same record from two different computers. Application on PC1 first loads record for editing, than app. on second PC loads same record. When I change some data in loaded record on PC2 and press Save it stores changed values even if the same record is firstly opened by PC1. How to tell to applicaton on PC2 that the record is already loaded on PC1 and chaning is not allowed? Is it possible?

Comment: Do you do that within the same transaction? If not - you need to implement some application level pessimistic locking strategy.

Comment: I always start new transaction while doing update